# How do I wire these LEDs in parallel?

Tags: led, circuit-design, wiring

So I got these COB LEDs, and I want to wire them in parallel.

On one side, they have contacts labeled +/- and on the other there are two contacts labeled +/-B

[image]

How do I wire these?  I am not quite sure what this -B is all about.

Comment: Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the the LEDs.

Comment: The product speicifications are here: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1000006354595.html?spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.6fee4c4dooVunC (12010)

No data sheet was provided

Comment: No datasheet? No sale!

Comment: Any idea what -B could mean in general?

Comment: At that wattage and size, you will *need* to heat-sink them per the datash--- oh, never mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a multimeter continuity feature to confirm that the two + and - connections are just pass through and connected together.

These cobs are designed to run straight off 12V. So you just wire them in parallel. But keep in mind these are supposed 10W each, so they will heat up. And that they are unregulated so if the voltage goes up the current draw will increase. Use an appropriately sized resistor or add a voltage regulator to keep it at a reasonable voltage and current.

At 10W you probably want some heatsinking or fan as well.

[image]

Comment: @j... if you want them to burn out in hours, sure connect them unregulated to a 14.6V active car power system.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably these boards have solid wires going lengthwise just for connecting them in parallel, but mechanically in series. Such connection is also used in 12V LED stripes. You may check this easily with an ohmmeter.
I don't know if they have same, matched current-voltage ratings (they give 12-14 V range in specs), this means that there are no ballast resistors inside, then adding a resistor in series with each module is advised. This will limit current through modules which have lower voltage and decrease heating and overpower.

Answer (score 1):

Without the datasheet one cannot say definitively.

In the tube days there were A, B and C supplies as a convention where "B" was the battery. You may find this in automotive work as well "B" for battery.
Disclaimer> We are guessing without the datasheet
https://antiqueradios.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=318743

Comment: A and C were also frequently batteries.